# How to stop receiving multiple copies of a mailing list email in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003, mailing-lists

My company has various internal mailing lists, I am a member of various ones. If I receive a message addressed to two (or more!) groups of which I am a member, I receive two copies of the message.

Is there an option or trick I can use when I receive a message addressed to two lists of which I am a member, that when I read one message, it marks as read the others?

Comment: What mail server are you using?  If you're using Microsoft Exchange with Exchange-managed mailing lists, you should only receive one copy of the message in the scenario you describe.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you either need:

- [a server fix](https://serverfault.com/) on your company's mailing lists

or

- a duplicate message remover for outlook 2003. 
  [There are](http://www.ablebits.com/outlook-remove-duplicate-emails/index.php) [a few](http://www.office-addins.com/-outlook-addins/duplicate-email-remover.html), but I don't [see any](http://www.google.com/search?q=outlook+2003+duplicate+email+remover) that are free.

Answer (score 0):

The following article discusses quite a few dupe removers : ["Duplicate Remover Tools for Microsoft Outlook"](http://www.slipstick.com/addins/mail_duplicates.asp). None of them seem to be free.

Answer (score 0):

Likely a configuration error with your account on the Exchange server. (if you guys are using Exchange.)